# collectionView is nil in UICollectionViewController loaded from Xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, swift

The title basically says it all. I'm trying to create a collection view with a `UICollectionViewController` that is defined in a Xib file. My `UICollectionViewController` uses a custom base class and when I try to access `collectionView` in its `viewDidLoad()`, `collectionView` is `nil`. Code is very straightforward.

Can somebody tell me why collectionView is `nil` when the `UICollectionViewController` is loaded from a Xib and how to fix this? When I instantiate the `UICollectionViewController` programmatically everything works but I'd prefer to create the `UICollectionViewController` in a Xib file.

**UPDATE:**

[image]

Comment: have you add Delegate & DataSource to UICollectionView in XIB??

Comment: You need something tutorial like UICollectionView with XIB cell right?

Comment: @iBhavin See screenshot above. The collectionView is connected to my custom UICollectionViewControl class's as dataSource and delegate. This was set automatically. But it doesn't work.

Comment: `when I try to access collectionView in its viewDidLoad(), collectionView is nil.` Do you mean that `println(collectionView)` inside the `viewDidLoad:` method of your collectionViewController class returns `nil`?

Answer (score 2):

Check your Xib delegate setting and code, follow these:

[image]

regist cell:

[_collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:Cell_Identifier];

And see API document and demo directly:
http://developer.apple.com/library/etc/redirect/xcode/ios/889e4b/samplecode/CollectionView-Simple/Introduction/Intro.html

The new screenshot and code.

[image]

[image]

```
-(UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:                      (UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section

    {
        UIEdgeInsets top = {10,25,15,25};
        return top;
    }

-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    CGSize size = {25,25};
    return size;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    CGSize size = {25,25};
    return size;
}

-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(70, 70);
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 30;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 30;
}
```

Comment: I suspected it has something to do with the delegate outlets. But please see my now attached screenshot above. There is no such a thing like a File's Owner listed anywhere in my IB (this is Xcode 6 beta 6). The data source and delegate of the collectionView are automatically set to GridViewCtrl (which is my custom UICollectionViewControl class). What should I do?

Comment: Beside above, UICollectionViewFlowLayout is required, the new additional is XIB and code setting, please see the screenshot and code method.

Answer (score 0):

try it [here](https://github.com/lequysang/TestCollectionViewWithXIB).

The Example create collectionView with Xib